# Fastlane upload_to_testflight The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, itmstransporter, fastlane-pilot

I'm trying to run fastlane to upload in App Store however I'm facing some issue.

Here is my fastlane env below:

```
### Stack

| Key                         | Value                                       |
| --------------------------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.15.6                                     |
| Ruby                        | 2.7.2                                       |
| Bundler?                    | false                                       |
| Git                         | git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)          |
| Installation Source         | ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/fastlane         |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G73)                    |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib                |
| OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020                  |
| Is contained                | false                                       |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                       |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                       |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version               | 12.3                                        |


### System Locale

| Error                       |
| --------------------------- |
| No Locale with UTF8 found  |


### fastlane files:

**No Fastfile found**


**No Appfile found**


### fastlane gems

| Gem      | Version | Update-Status |
| -------- | ------- | ------------- |
| fastlane | 2.173.0 | ✅ Up-To-Date
```

Here is the command I run

`fastlane upload_to_testflight_beta`

Here is the command output:

```
WARN [2021-02-05 15:38:39.87]: [iTMSTransporter] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

WARN [2021-02-05 15:38:39.87]: [iTMSTransporter]    ... 6 more

INFO [2021-02-05 15:38:39.87]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
ERROR [2021-02-05 15:38:39.87]: The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
WARN [2021-02-05 15:38:40.03]: Lane Context:
INFO [2021-02-05 15:38:40.03]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios upload_to_testflight_beta", :SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE=>"app-store", :MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING=>{"com.xxx.XManagement.ios"=>"match AppStore com.xxx.XManagement.ios 1612510700"}}
ERROR [2021-02-05 15:38:40.03]: Error uploading ipa file, for more information see above
INFO [2021-02-05 15:38:40.03]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/Users/john.devera/code/MOBILE/crew-management-ios/fastlane/README.md'

+------+----------------------+-------------+
|             fastlane summary              |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action               | Time (in s) |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| 1    | update_fastlane      | 2           |
| 2    | default_platform     | 0           |
| 3    | match                | 20          |
|    | upload_to_testflight | 14          |
+------+----------------------+-------------+

ERROR [2021-02-05 15:38:40.06]: fastlane finished with errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from /Users/john.devera/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

If someone please could help me.

I'm new in iOS development and I'm using Swift and fastlane to develop my app.

Thanks

Comment: Have you switched to api keys for your connections to App Store connect?

Comment: @Paulw11 Figured out the problem. It seems some firewall or networking issue is blocking the itmstransporter for proceeding. When I try to deploy in other network its now working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The problem was I was connected to a network that has some firewall that seems to blocking something related to `itmstransporter` when deploying.

Comment: This support article may be helpful for some.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

Comment: I have the same issue. I can not change the network because of the company's rules. How can I fix get over this step? Any advice should be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain how did you unblocked it from the firewall

Answer (score 2):

If you use the ENV value, you can solve this problem.

> example

`Fastfile`

```
 ENV['ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD'] = 'true'
...
```

OR

`shell`

```
export ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD=true && bundle exec fastlane ios upload_test_flight
```